# Browser can't render the circle

Tags: html

I have this script and markup.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:aqua" > 
</canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 10;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
context.stroke();
</script>
```

The problem is , the browser depicts an eclipse instead of circle. why is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have distorted your canvas by changing its size with CSS styles. Instead, set its size using the `height` and `width` properties directly on the tag:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100" style="background-color:aqua">
```

The circle-to-elipse distortion arises because canvas are by default wider than they are tall, but you have used CSS to force the browser to render a wide rectangle of canvas pixels as a square. By using `height` and `width` properties, you change the number of pixels in the canvas, instead of changing the size they occupy.

Comment: Thanks @apsillers. So you mean canvas has a different coordinate system that can be set by these attrs?